# How to get historic VIX data in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I could get price of a stock on a data using

```
=INDEX(=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","price","4/26/2019"),2,2)
```

But same formula doesn't work for `VIX`

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("VIX")
```

does return current value of `VIX`.

How can I get `VIX` on a specific date?

Comment: I can get latest value using, `=GOOGLEFINANCE("VIX")`
But I would like to get value on a particular date for example, 
VIX close value on 26th APR is 12.73,
VVIX is different from VIX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across a similar issue where `=GoogleFinance` seems to have missing data for certain stocks, on certain dates.

One alternative free data source is MarketWatch, and I found that below is able to retrieve VIX on 4/26/2019:

`=index(importhtml("http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/historical/default.asp?symb=vix&closeDate=4%2F26%2F19&x=41&y=17","Table"), 3, 2)`

For my own issue, it seemed like it had trouble with market closed days (i.e. weekends and NASDAQ holidays), and I was able to force it to approximate price with this formula:

`=index(GoogleFinance("AMZN", "price", WORKDAY(E20+1,-1,'Market Closed Days'!Q2:Q10),1),2,2)`

Where I specified the date in cell E20, and a list of NASDAQ holidays in a sheet named Market Closed Days in cells Q2:Q10. This does not seem to be the case for 4/26/2019, but I wanted to share it in case it is helpful for others.

Answer (score 3):

You can get CBOE Indexes in Google Finance without scraping.

e.g.

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("INDEXCBOE:VIX")
```

or

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("INDEXCBOE:VIX3M")
```

Comment: I don't know why this one is downvoted, but this is the best answer for me work like a charm!